# How can I catch a file not found type error while using wxFileConfig in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I have something like this:

```
self.locale_directory = os.getcwd() + "/locale"
if os.path.exists(self.locale_directory):
    self.file_content = wx.FileConfig(localFilename = os.path.join(self.locale_directory, "languages.ini"))
    # I want to handle error in case file not found
```

How do I know if an error occured while trying to open/read the actual file ?

Comment: `try` opening it manually beforehand or test for its presence.You are already testing for the directory.

Comment: Worked well with the second clue, i.e. by testing for its presence with `os.path.isfile`. This solution can be created as an answer.

Comment: use try except statemend and do something if the except statement has been activated

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit to spending no time on my comment, it was just a quick, how to get it done, type of thing.
I don't know when `wx.FileConfig` was added to `wxpython` but it didn't exist a few years ago. Thus I've always used `configobj` or `configparser`.

Both provide a straightforward method of failing when the input file does not exist and take the grunt work out of handling the variables and variable types, along with providing defaults for variables which are not present.
I heartily commend both of them for handling your `ini` type file requirements.
Of the two, `configobj` is the more complicated but does provide a sophistication that some might require.
I'd suggest try running with `configparser` first, until you find something that it can't do.